# Does the performance of a MySQL VARCHAR(n) table dgrade regularly with the value of n?

Tags: mysql

Or is MySQL optimized for certain values of n, e.g., powers of 2?

Comment: what do you mean by 'degrade'? Why would it.

Comment: Not sure - nothing is free.  If it doesn't in some way degrade, why ever say VARCHAR(10) rather than VARCHAR(65000)?

Comment: there are many reasons, the primary one being 'Model your Domain accurately'.

Comment: If you haven't measured there's a problem , stop worrying about problems you don't have!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MySQL keeps extra information about exactly how long the string in a certain VARCHAR field is. It needs either 1 or 2 bytes to store this data. Upto 255 bytes, MySQL will need only 1 extra byte to store the length of the VARCHAR. Above 255, it will use 2 bytes. So there's one instance where a certain n will matter. But other than that, shorter is much better because MySQL will need to use much more memory when doing things involving this VARCHAR column. Doing things like sorting or operations that use in-memory temporary tables will cost a lot more if you have a VARCHAR(1000) vs VARCHAR(20).

There is a good few pages that cover this in the Schema Optimization and Indexing chapter of High Performance MySQL from Oreilly.

Answer (score 1):

It isn't optimised for any kind of pattern of sizes - it's a simple case of larger varchar fields take longer to handle (oo-er). The only way to optimise it is to limit it to whatever is the longest it ever needs to be.